# Calculation of Hex grid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, hexagonal-tiles

What i would like to do is create a hex grid like below.

[image: Hex grid]

I can draw the hex but unsure how to get them to stagger. So first row should be
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) in the image and the second row should be  (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) ect Where the even hex in the row is always staggered down.

Currently I know the number of rows / columns to use 
`hexRows`
`hexColumns`

and how i draw the hex is like this, `i` is just there to number the hex when its drawn. 
`DrawSolidHex(x,y,i);`

current code looks like this

```
 begin
 hexcolumns := c;
 hexrows := r;
 i:=1;             //first cube
 x := 1;           //default x,y,z values
 y := 1;
 z := 0;
   while hexrows>0 do
    begin
      columnssave := hexcolumns ;
      while hexcolumns >0 do
        begin
          DrawSoildHex(X,Y,i);
          i:=i+1;
          x := x + 1; 
          hexcolumns := hexcolumns -1;
        end;
      y:=y+1;
      x:= 1;
      z:=0;
      hexcolumns := columnssave;
      hexrows:= hexrows-1;
    end;
    totalhex := i;
```

With this code  currently it will just draw the hex x,y in a stright line,(1,1) (2,1) (3,1)..ect I am unsure how to add the offsets ,calculate them, and code it so it would stagger the rows.

Comment: *I can draw the hex but unsure how to get them to stagger.* That's very odd. If you can draw one hexagon, you can draw them all. If you draw one, you've already drawn the shared lines between all the neighbours. So you already know where to draw the neighbours.

Comment: yes i know where to draw them, but there has to be a calculation involved as to how to calculate the next xy

Comment: You don't understand. If you can draw one, you already know where to draw all the neighbours. You've already done the calculations.

Comment: I can draw one cause i can tell it where to draw, i dont know where to tell it to draw the next neighboring one relevant to the one it just drew.

Comment: I tell it where to draw? What does that mean? In order to draw a hexagon you have to draw 6 lines. Is that correct. So, you know where those 6 lines are. Right? I cannot make any sense of your assertion that you are able to draw this hexagon without knowing where it is, and where the lines are. How could you draw these lines without specifying where they are.

Comment: no need for double comments see below on how i draw it with out drawing the lines

Comment: Bods, this has actually turned out to be quite an interesting topic so I've covered it in more depth in my blog (http://powerfield-software.com/?p=851 which is scheduled for publication in about 15 hours). It's an expansion on the points I laid out in my answer below, and with much nicer graphics :-) It also has code which may be of use to you, Glen (though it's in Python, it should translate well enough to Delphi).

Comment: As a little side note,  due to using firemonkey's TCylinder and changing the setting so its a 6 sided hexagon. Width and Height are NOT for the hexagon. Depth is for the hexagon.  just a FYI  :D

Comment: This is required reading: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a hexagon as follows, you need to know about the triangles that make up the edges:

```
    B                   B
    *--*                *
   /|   \              /|
  / |    \            / |
A*--*C    *  ==>   c /  | a
  \      /          /   |
   \    /          /    |
    *--*         A*-----*C
                     b
```

These triangles are known as 30-60-90 triangles because that's the angles making up the inner corners: `C = 90`, `A = 60`, `B = 30`.

The ratios of the sides for those triangles is `c = 2`, `b = 1` and `a = sqrt(3)`.

So, assuming you know `c` (it's the length of one of the hexagon sides), you can calculate the other two sides of that triangle without having to resort to trigonometry functions:

```
a = c * sqrt(3) / 2
b = c / 2
```

Once we know those values, the hexagon offsets are relatively easy to calculate just by eyeballing your grid and using the leftmost corner (`A` in my diagram above) of each hexagon as the start and end points.

The horizontal distance from `(0,0)` to `(0,1)` is `b + c + b - b` (heading northeast, east, southeast and southwest). That's the horizontal difference between all "adjacent"  cells in a row and it simplifies to `b + c`, or `3 * c / 2` if you just want to use `c`.

The vertical distance from `(0,0)` to `(0,1)` (half a row) is simply `a` (southeast then the irrelevant east). That's equivalent to `sqrt(3) * c / 2` or probably close enough to `c * 433 / 500` (an error of one part in 16,000) as to not have to involve even square roots.

Although, if you'd prefer more accuracy, you could stick with the square root calculations - just remember to work out `sqrt(3) / 2` once at the start and just use that as the multiplier.

The vertical distance between rows is obviously double that, say for `(0,0)` to `(1,0)`.

So, for every full row, you simply move down `c * 433 / 250` units. For every column, you move across `c * 3 / 2` units and vertically `c * 433 / 500` units (down if you're moving from an even index to an odd one, otherwise up).

Comment: +1 for a delightful answer. Although you did resort to trig to calculate the lengths of the sides of the triangles. ;-)

Comment: Some good info here, I will see if i can use this to get it to offset in the code, but does clear up at least half of my question.

Comment: Pythagorean's Theorm was taught to me Geometry class, not Trig. In Trig class, they assumed you already knew this stuff cold. Trig is where you get into the ratios between the legs and the hypotenuse, which is sin, cos, tan, etc. :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know you can put this into codeing terms  :D

Comment: Technically speaking, in the staggered rows, you only need to draw one horizontal line (the top) per hex cell, and possibly more in the last row. You might be better off simply drawing across the page rather than each cell. There's no loss of pixels, but if this is on a printed device, you could end up with multiple drawing strokes that use up ink needlessly.

Comment: @David You cannot do this with Pythagoras. You need some trig somewhere along the line. You can get to 30-60-90 with basic geometry. Then you need some trig for the next step.

Comment: @Glen I know you can write the code for this. This answers your entire question.

Comment: I see the need for pre-computed sqrts, not any trancendental functions.

Comment: Well, in fairness, the ratios of the sides of a 30-60-90 triangle need trig for proof but I started with that proof as a given. Not rigourous but sometimes it's better to be pragmaic :-)

Comment: @David pax understands me. You need trig to write down expressions for the lengths. Yes, you evaluate it with sqrt, but how did you write down sqrt(3) in the first place?

Comment: @paxdiablo  ok the height is 2 and width is 2,  Thus (a) or (C) to (B) is 1.  how do i now find (c)

Comment: @Glen, I started with the premise you would know c, the length of the side but you could equally start with the height/width of the whole shape. The height is 2a, the width is c+2b, or 2c.

Comment: @paxdiablo well i know the height is 2 which would be `2a = 2` which now `a = 1`  and i know width so `2c = 2` which now `c = 1`  but that cant be, as c has to be bigger then a..

Comment: What if instead of a 30 60 90 , you did a 60 , 60  , 60  maybe those cal would be eaiser?

Comment: @Glen, those calcs may well be easier but then it's not a hexagon, and probably wouldn't tessellate that well :-)

Comment: @GlenMorse Adding to that, you don't need just a hexagon, you need a **regular** hexagon. That is a 6 sided polygon where all sides have the same length, and as a corollary, all internal angles are the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you used any to points that are next to each other and the 3rd point is the middle of the hexagon. that would give you the 60, 60 ,60 triangle. And would still be a REGULAR hexagon correct?

Comment: That's right. Pax thought you meant replacing his triangle with yours. Anyway, as I already said, if you can draw one regular hexagon, you can draw them all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the problem is not drawing it , but placing it

Comment: Sigh. You need to know where to place it to draw it. If you draw one regular hexagon then you draw 6 line segments. Each of those line segments is shared with a neighbour. Therefore if you can draw one, you can draw them all. In order to draw one, you need to know where each of the line segments is placed. That in turn tells you where to place one of the line segments of each neighbour and that is enough to tell you where to place all the others.

Comment: I dont draw it by points, I place a component at (X,Y) thus I am sure somewhere in the background the points are being calculated. But I am sure it would be harder to find them and use them

Comment: Well I guess that's the problem. Using components to draw simple regular polygons is not ideal. I suggest you paint the grid directly. The question makes no mention of any components. So it's hardly surprising we imagined that you needed help with geometry. I don't think we can help you with this component, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan its a simple TSpare delphi component. And painting to grid directly would involve creating a new component to do the same this this one does. Which my question is not about, its about how to calculate the next x, y

Comment: It is possible to paint without components. However, if you insist on doing it with these components, then you should ask that. I'm going to have to downvote your question because you appear to have asked the wrong question. You did not mention the component you use, and you did not ask what you really appear to want to know. My advice, feel free to ignore it, is to paint this grid yourself.

Comment: I am asking what i want to know. Your solution is plot each point, which i have done before. but did not like it, and using an allready built component is alot less code. I know my question.. How to find the next xy of the following hex. NOT how to paint a hex grid

Comment: Please can you edit the question to make it really clear what you are asking. You need to tell us how you specify the dimension of the hexagon. Which dimension do you specify. If you can do that it's simple. In fact the maths in pax's answer tells you all you need. But I think that this maths is perhaps a little beyond you so you'll need somebody to spell it out for you. Many of us could do that. Please just tell us how you specify the hexagon's size.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry If i am not clear but all i do is set the width and height on the component to 2 int he object inspector. It then creates the hexagon. With no information on the size to the sides or the points.  Then i set the position to x1 y1 z0

Comment: What is the definition of width and height for a hexagon? All this needs to go in the question. We cannot answer based on information supplied in comments to another answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan good point, SO i cant define the Width and Height. cause if i define them as 2 and 2 its not a regular hexagon. Thus i set width to 2 and height is now sqr(3).  Why did you not jsut say that!

Comment: The width of a hexagon of side length `x` is `2 * x`. Its height is `x * sqrt(3)`. It won't be a "square" shape.

Comment: @GlenMorse Why did I not define what you mean by width and height? Because it is your job to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with simple calculations, if you know (you should) the size of the hex cells.

```
   | small |
   | width |
    _______  ______
   /       \       h
  /         \      e
 /           \     i
 \           /     g
  \         /      h
|  \_______/ _|____t
|             |
|--- width ---|
```

```
uses
  System.Types,
  Vcl.Graphics;

type
  THexCellSize = record
    Width : Integer;
    Height : Integer;
    SmallWidth : Integer;
  end;

function GetHexDrawPoint( AHexCellSize : THexCellSize; ACol, ARow : Integer ) : TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := ( ( AHexCellSize.Width - AHexCellSize.SmallWidth ) div 2 + AHexCellSize.SmallWidth ) * ACol;
  Result.Y := AHexCellSize.Height * ARow + ( AHexCellSize.Height div 2 ) * ( ACol mod 2 );
end;

procedure DrawHexCell( ACanvas : TCanvas; AOffSet : TPoint; AHexCellSize : THexCellSize; ACol, ARow : Integer );
var
  LPoint : TPoint;
  LXOffset : Integer;
begin
  { *************
    *   1---2
    *  /     \
    * 6       3
    *  \     /
    *   5---4
    ************* }

  LXOffset := ( AHexCellSize.Width - AHexCellSize.SmallWidth ) div 2;

  // Move to point 1
  LPoint := GetHexDrawPoint( AHexCellSize, ACol, ARow );
  LPoint.Offset( AOffSet );
  ACanvas.MoveTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
  // Line to point 2
  LPoint.Offset( AHexCellSize.SmallWidth, 0 );
  ACanvas.LineTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
  // Line to point 3
  LPoint.Offset( LXOffset, AHexCellSize.Height div 2 );
  ACanvas.LineTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
  // Line to point 4
  LPoint.Offset( -LXOffset, AHexCellSize.Height div 2 );
  ACanvas.LineTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
  // Line to point 5
  LPoint.Offset( -AHexCellSize.SmallWidth, 0 );
  ACanvas.LineTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
  // Line to point 6
  LPoint.Offset( -LXOffset, -AHexCellSize.Height div 2 );
  ACanvas.LineTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
  // Line to point 1
  LPoint.Offset( LXOffset, -AHexCellSize.Height div 2 );
  ACanvas.LineTo( LPoint.X, LPoint.Y );
end;

procedure DrawHexCellGrid( ACanvas : TCanvas; AOffSet : TPoint; AHexCellSize : THexCellSize; ACols, ARows : Integer );
var
  LCol, LRow : Integer;
begin
  for LRow := 0 to ARows - 1 do
    for LCol := 0 to ACols - 1 do
      DrawHexCell( ACanvas, AOffSet, AHexCellSize, LCol, LRow );
end;
```